# Regarding use of hadoop for execution of multiple independent actions

Tags: hadoop

I have several independent actions(For e.g to send command to a outside device) and consider actions count can be > 400. 
question: Is it possible to use Hadoop from java to execute these independent actions concurrently by using multiple systems or nodes in a network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not usual use of hadoop, it is possible
 Here you will use hadoop only as distributed task executor. 
One of the ways to do so - is to create input files with commands you want to execute (or any other description of tasks you want to do) and then make mapper to execute them. 
If you keep command per line - you do not need any special input format - default text input format will do.